# Problemas con la carga de Glide

Tags: android-studio, firebase, android-listview, android-glide

tenemos en nuestro proyecto varios ListView y GridView.
Descargo de Firebase varias imágenes para que carguen y hasta ahí bien, el problema es que cuando hago roll, hacía arriba y hacía abajo las imágenes que cargaron antes se descolocan, se colocan otras y tratan de recargar de nuevo.
La verdad es que hemos tenido problemas desde el principio pues teníamos Glide pero no GlideApp, pero aún así sigue sin ir correctamente, tampoco guarda en Cache para que las imágenes continúen en caso de no tener internet.
Adjunto un vídeo para que se vea mejor a lo que me refiero: https://youtu.be/8XNdLyECVzU

-- Activity --

```
ListView listCB;

//ADAPTADOR
ArrayList<ZDescuento> lista_tiendas = new ArrayList<ZDescuento>();

//ETIQUETAS SUBIDA DE BASE DE DATOS
DatabaseReference dbRef;
ValueEventListener valueEventListener;

static final String EXTRA_USUARIO="USUARIO";
static final String EXTRA_DESCUENTO = "DESCUENTO";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cbdescuentos);

    cargardatos();

    //ENLAZO VARIANTES DECLARADAS
    listCB = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listCB);

}//FIN ONCREATE

//BASE DE LIST VIEW
private void cargarListView(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    //ENLAZAR DATOS FIREBASE
    lista_tiendas.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(ZDescuento.class));

    //ADAPTADOR
    ZAdaptadorDescuento adaptador = new ZAdaptadorDescuento( this, lista_tiendas);
    listCB.setAdapter(adaptador);

    listCB.setOnItemClickListener
            (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    //CREAR ETIQUETAS A LOS ELEMENTOS DE LA LISTVIEW

                    //REFERENCIA A LA CLASE + UNA LETRA
                    ZDescuento p = ((ZDescuento) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    String imagen = p.getImagen();
                    String nombre = p.getNombre();
                    String descripcioncorta = p.getDescripcioncorta();
                    String lugar = p.getLugar();
                    ZDescuento descuentoenviado = new ZDescuento(imagen, nombre, descripcioncorta, lugar);

                    //ETIQUETA + INDICAR A QUE MAINACTIVITY VA A IR
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DADescuentoActivity.class);

                    //DECIR QUE DATOS DEBE PASAR AL PRÓXIMO MAIN ACTIVITY (EXTRA CREAR EN ETIQUETAS)
                    i.putExtra(EXTRA_DESCUENTO, descuentoenviado);
                    i.putExtra(EXTRA_USUARIO, p);

                    //INICIAR ACTIVITY
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
}

//CARGA DE BASE DE DATOS DE FIREBASE
private void cargardatos() {

    //CARGAR LA CACHE (QUE QUEDE EN EL STORAGE AUNQUE NO TENGA DATOS)
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

    //CARGAR UN DETERMINADO BASE DE DATOS DE FIREBASE
    dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("descuento");

    //AÑADIMOS EL EVENTO QUE NOS DEVUELVE LOS VALORES
    valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //BORRAR DATOS
            lista_tiendas.clear();
            //DECIR QUE DATOS DEBE CARGAR
            for (DataSnapshot tiendaDataSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                cargarListView(tiendaDataSnapShot);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("CBDescuentosActivity", "DATABASE ERROR");
        }
    };

    //PARA QUE SEA A TIEMPO REAL
    dbRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
}


public void cargarbusquedafirebase(View view) {

    //CARGAR UN DETERMINADO BASE DE DATOS DE FIREBASE
    dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("descuento");

    //AÑADIMOS EL EVENTO QUE NOS DEVUELVE LOS VALORES
    valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //BORRAR DATOS
            lista_tiendas.clear();
            //DECIR QUE DATOS DEBE CARGAR
            for (DataSnapshot tiendaDataSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                cargarBusqueda(tiendaDataSnapShot);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("CBDescuentosActivity", "DATABASE ERROR");

        }
    };

    //PARA QUE SEA A TIEMPO REAL
    dbRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
}
```

-- Adaptador --

```
public class ZAdaptadorDescuento extends ArrayAdapter<ZDescuento> {


ArrayList<ZDescuento> tiendas;
Context c;
LayoutInflater inflater;

//CARGA DE NUBE IMAGEN
StorageReference storageReference;


public ZAdaptadorDescuento(Context c, ArrayList<ZDescuento> tiendas){
    super(c, R.layout.list_cb_decuentos, tiendas);
    this.tiendas = tiendas;
    this.c = c;
    this.storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (null == convertView) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_cb_decuentos, parent, false);
    }

    //RELLENAR LOS ITEM CREADOS
    //ITEM SOCIO HACE REFERENCIA AL LAYOUT CREADO INDIVIDUAL

    //TITULO
    TextView tv_nombretienda = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvtitulolistcb);
    tv_nombretienda.setText(tiendas.get(position).getNombre());

    //DESCRIPCION
    TextView tv_descripcion = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvdescripcionlistcb);
    tv_descripcion.setText(tiendas.get(position).getDescripcioncorta());

    //LUGAR
    TextView tv_lugar = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvlugarlistcb);
    tv_lugar.setText(tiendas.get(position).getLugar());

    //CAJA
    String imagen_logo = tiendas.get(position).getImagen();
    ImageView imagen_tienda = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagempresalistcb);

    cargarImagen (imagen_logo,convertView,imagen_tienda);

    return convertView;

}

//CARGA DE LA IMAGEN DE LA BASE DE DATOS
private void cargarImagen(String imagen_logo,final View convertView, final ImageView imagen_tienda){
    storageReference.child("descuentos").child(imagen_logo).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                GlideApp
                        .with(convertView)
                        .load(uri.toString())
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
                        .into(imagen_tienda);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: "teníamos Glide pero no GlideApp" ¿quiere decir que estas usando GlideApp?, el titulo de tu pregunta habla de "Glade", te sugiero modifiques tu pregunta para que sea más entendible , revisa  [ask], saludos.

Comment: Buenas, creo que en ningún sitio hemos puesto "Glade", o no lo vemos la verdad. Lo que quiero decir con "teníamos Glide pero no GlideApp", es que he visto que se puede formular el código con Glide o GlideApp, y uno es más obsoleto que otro, dentro de la librería Glide

Answer (score 0):

ya hemos encontrado la solución. :D
Estabamos recogiendo la imagen del Storage con su nombre de archivo, y aunque realmente descarga y se veía la imagen, no se mantenía en la pantalla.
Cambiamos en el Firebase nombre del archivo por enlace del archivo URL, y luego probamos con Picasso y con Glide que en lugar de recoger los nombres del Storage, recogiese las URLs de las imágenes.

AHORA:

```
        //CAJA
    ImageView imagen_tienda = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagempresalistcb);
    String url = socios.get(position).getImagen();
    GlideApp
            .with(c)
            .load(url)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imagen_tienda);

    return convertView;

}
```